# What does "a least-squares approximation to a sequence of data is simply their averaged value (mathematical expectation)" mean?

Tags: error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

I am reading the paper "Multiscale coarse graining of liquid-state systems" (https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2038787). In the paper, right after equation (1), they say "a least-squares approximation to a sequence of data is simply their averaged value (mathematical expectation)".

They use it as a justification to convert their least-square force-matching problem, to an averaging problem. My question is, when did least squares mean "average value"?

Let's consider a super simple problem of trying to predict $y$ from $x$ using function $g$ with parameter $t$, so $$y=g(x,t)$$

If I collect $N$ data points, my LSE would be
$$LSE = \sum_{i=1}^N (y_i-g(x_i,t))(y_i-g(x_i,t))$$
differentiating with respect to $t$, and equating to zero, you get:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N g'(x_i,t)(y_i - g(x_i,t))=0$$

I don't see how they can simply make the claim that "a least-squares approximation to a sequence of data is simply their averaged value"?

Any advice you have regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your result depends on there being an independent variable ($x_i$). Is there an appropriate $x_i$ in the data set in the paper? If there isn't (or if all $x_i$ are equal), then you'll get the result that the MMSE estimate for the true value of $y$ is the mean of the $y_i$.

Comment: " expection"  is not a word. I expect that you have miss spelled "expectation in your statements and title

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Updated response to provide more information.

Let X and Y be random variables, and x and y be specific values of these random variables.  Is Y is completely dependent on X, then there is a function y(x) that gives a unique y for each x, such as $y(x) = ax^2$ or $y(x) = mx + b$.  If a function exists, then y is completely dependent on x.  If the function is linear in x, then y and x are linearly dependent (completely correlated).  *(Note: uncorrelated does not imply independent; for $y = ax^2$, Y and X are uncorrelated, but Y depends on X.  Independent does imply uncorrelated.)*

Suppose we have two random variables Y and X and we expect Y to be somewhat linearly dependent on X; for example, if X is the net worth for a person and Y is the value of the home for that person.  We take a sample of X and record the value x, and record the y for that x.  If we plot the y vs. x values and see that a straight-line fit is reasonable (or more rigorously run standard tests to determine if there is a significant correlation), the best straight-line fit is determined by regression (a least squares evaluation) and using the least-squares evaluation the y values along the line are the best estimate (mean) values of y for x.  That is, for a given x, the distribution of y values has a mean that lies along the regression line.  In that sense, the y values are means.  *(This is rigorously true if for every x value, there is a random variable Y having a normal distribution and all the Y distributions have the same variance. But, results are not seriously affected if departures from normal distributions and equal variances are not too extreme.)*

If there is complete correlation based on the sample, the linear correlation coefficient is +1, and y is a linear function of x with no uncertainty.

A good elementary discussion of all this is given in the text Elementary Statistics by Triola.  More details are found in advanced statistics tests.

Answer (score 0):

The fit, which minimises the root mean square value, is a fit to the "average values". To see this let's consider an example. Suppose we have five different input parameters $x_i = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_5\}$ and that we take for each setting ten data point $y_{ij} = \{y_{1,1}, \ldots, y_{1,10}, y_{2,1}, \ldots, y_{2,10}, \ldots y_{5,10}\}$. If we use the least-square fit to find the optimal model $\hat y(x) = c x + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a random error, we obtain the same result, for the two following procedure:

1. Fit the model to the all data $(x_i, y_{ij})$, or
2. first calculate the average value for each parameter,
   $\bar y_{.j} = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10} y_{j}$ and then fit the model to the averages $(x_i, \bar y_{.j})$.

This is evident when you look at a fitted line, e.g.
[image]

Here the R-code used to produce the plot

```
# set a seed for random numbers:
set.seed(1121)

# set true values by random sampling:
slope     = rnorm(1,mean=0, sd=5)
intercept = rnorm(1,mean=0, sd=5)

# get input parameters:
x = seq(-3, 10, length.out=5)
X = rep(x, 10) # just copy data multiple time

# get measurement values
Y = slope*X + rnorm(10*5, mean=0, sd=3) # add a random error

# plot:
df = data.frame(x=X, y=Y)
library(ggplot2)
gg = ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_point(color="blue", alpha=0.6) +
    labs(x="Input parameters", y="Measurements")
print(gg)

# fit:
gg2 = gg + geom_smooth(method='lm', formula="y~x", color="red", alpha=0.1)
print(gg2)

lm.out = lm(y ~ x, df)
print(lm.out)

# fit2:
dim(X) = c(10,5)
dim(Y) = c(10,5)
yMean  = mean.rowwise(Y)
df2    = data.frame(x, y=yMean)
lm.out2 = lm(y ~ x, df2)
print(lm.out2)
```